# datatables does not print ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```js
$.ajax({  
                url:'a.php',  
                method:'POST',  
                data:{s:s1, month:s2, year:s3},  
                dataType:'json',  
                success:function(data){ 
     var a = data[0];
     //var b = data[1];
     // var len = b.length;
     var t = document.getElementById('tbl_1');
                    $(t).find('td:eq(2)').text(a[0].a);
     $(t).find('td:eq(3)').text(a[0].b);
     $(t).find('td:eq(4)').text(a[0].bd);
     
     
     $(t).find('td:eq(5)').text(a[0].ab);
     $(t).find('td:eq(6)').text(a[0].bc);
     
     $(t).find('td:eq(7)').text(a[0].bo);
     
          }
          });
```

i want to print my table i have been following these two examples 
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/simple.html
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/columns.html

button are showing and working but in my case few table cells are populating from database. ajax is working fine and data is displaying from database but when i click on print data is not shown my table structure is this

```html
<div class="panel-body">
                            <div style = "width:97%" >
       <h3 align="center" style="text-transform: uppercase">------: </h3><br>
      <br>
                                <table id = "tbl_1" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" >
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase">Sr.No</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase">a</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase"> b</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase">c </th>
 <th style="font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase">d</th>
 <th style="font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase">e</th>
 <th style="font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase">f</th>
 <th style="font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase">g</th>
                      
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
         
  <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td id = "af"></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2.</td>
        <td>b</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3.</td>
        <td>c</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4.</td>
        <td>d</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
      </tr>
   <tr>

        
  
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

my javascript code is here

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  

  
    $('#tbl_1').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'print',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            'colvis'
        ],
        // columnDefs: [ {
            // targets: -1,
            // visible: true
        // } ]
    } );

});
```

data is displaying in tables

[image]

but when i click on print table  is empty except design values like this

[image]

what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested it putting static data in `<td></td>`
and print worked fine printing with data in cell

so can you show your ajax function

My guess would be putting

//placing this part inside ajax success after `<td></td>` is finished being populated  from database in ajax

```
  $.ajax({  
                url:'a.php',  
                method:'POST',  
                data:{s:s1, month:s2, year:s3},  
                dataType:'json',  
                success:function(data){ 
                    var a = data[0];
                    //var b = data[1];
                    // var len = b.length;
                    var t = document.getElementById('tbl_1');
                    $(t).find('td:eq(2)').text(a[0].a);
                    $(t).find('td:eq(3)').text(a[0].b);
                    $(t).find('td:eq(4)').text(a[0].bd);


                    $(t).find('td:eq(5)').text(a[0].ab);
                    $(t).find('td:eq(6)').text(a[0].bc);

                    $(t).find('td:eq(7)').text(a[0].bo);



         $('#tbl_1').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'print',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            'colvis'
        ],
        // columnDefs: [ {
            // targets: -1,
            // visible: true
        // } ]
    } );


      }
      });
```

Comment: i have added ajax code . i am sorry i do not understand ur solution

Comment: can you show me from where  you are populating data in cell of table i.e in <td> </td>

Comment: $(t).find('td:eq(3)').text(a[0].b);

Comment: populating from database